# Launch existing project Django

Tags: django, virtualenv

I'm new to Django. I set up a Django project in a virtual environment a few days ago and worked on the project. Now I'm again trying to work on the project but when I try `python manage.py runserver`, it just runs a new "Welcome to Django" page and not the old project I was working in. How do I launch my existing virtualenv Django project rather than starting a new one?

Comment: turns out it works when I run `python manage.py runserver` from PyCharm IDE. Doesn't seem to work when running from a normal terminal. I'll stick to the IDE for the moment

Comment: As you mention you are new, don't forget to list your app name in the settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: My app was already listed to settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS during the last session

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added your application in the urls.py in your main project file, you could correct your problem with :

```
url(r'', include('Application.urls')),
```

Comment: That's not an answer, just a comment.